# Python, reading in 100+ tables from a txt file

Tags: python, datatable

I've got a very nasty table format which holds text and tables, and i need to read them in seperately.

The data looks like

```
table 1 text text text

log(x) a b c d e
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
7 8 9 0 1

table 2 text text text

log(x) a b c d e
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
7 8 9 0 1

etc
```

So it's the table title, the table header and then the table. 
I want jus the tables so the part with:

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
7 8 9 0 1
```

Any idea on how to do this in one go?

Answer (score 0):

If the tables are the only lines starting with digits you can use an inner loop to create the tables, breaking when we get to the end of each table:

```
from itertools import count


cn = count(1)
tables = {}
with open("in.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[0].isdigit():
            key = next(cn)
            tables[key] = [line.rstrip()]
            for line in f:
                if line[0].isdigit():
                    tables[key].append(line.rstrip())
                else:
                    break
print(tables)

{1: ['1 2 3 4 5', '2 3 4 5 6', '7 8 9 0 1'], 2: ['1 2 3 4 5', '2 3 4 5 6', '7 8 9 0 1']}
```

Or use `itertools.groupby` and create a list of lists:

```
from itertools import groupby

tables = {}
with open("in.txt") as f:
    for k,v in groupby(f,lambda x: x[0].isdigit()):
        if k:
            key = next(cn)
            tables[key] = [x.split() for x in v]

{1: [['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9', '0', '1']], 2: [['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9', '0', '1']]}
```

What format you want the output in you can decide yourself, if you want ints etc.. use `map(int,...`

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to read the file and process the information like shown in the following example?

```
file = open('testfile.txt','r')

text=file.read()
lines=text.split('\n')

tabs = []

for lineindex in range(len(lines)):
    if 'a b c d e' in lines[lineindex]:
        # this is just an idea...
        tabs.append(lines[lineindex+1 : lineindex+4])

file.close()

tabs
```

The output of `tabs` is a nested list. It contains lists, filled with table-values from the textfile.
Make sure that python finds the path to the file.

You could also watch out for the keyword 'table' in the loop and then form a dictionary which could look like this:

```
dictionary={
    'table 1': [data],
    'table 2': [data],
    'table 3': ...
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

A general solution (regardless of the values' type in the table) to your file's pattern is to remove unwanted lines (table name, headers, newlines), and retain the rest.

```
f = open('file.txt', 'r')
count_tables = 0
skip_lines = 0
for line in f.readlines():
    # We skip over the two unnecessary lines just above the table's entries
    if skip_lines != 0:
        skip_lines -= 1
        continue

    # We add a fully parsed table to a list at the occurrence of the following newline
    if(line.strip() == ''):
        if (count_tables != 0):
            dict_table = {'table_name': table_name,
                          'values': rows}
            list_tables.append(dict_table)
            rows = []
        continue
    # Else, we parse our table
    tokens = line.strip().split()    
    if (tokens[0] == 'table'):
        table_name = int(tokens[1])
        skip_lines = 2
        count_tables += 1
        continue

    row_vals = line.strip().split()
    rows.append(row_vals)

f.close()
```

This will give you a list of dictionaries, each containing a table_name entry and a list of values.